# Can it be safe to keep a copy of an std::initializer_list? What is the rationale?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, initializer-list

In my environment, the `std::initializer_list` is implemented as a pointer to the first element, and a size. Still in my specific setup, I was able to observe that:

- the underlying data is allocated in the current function frame (because the pointer to the first element says so)
- returning an `initializer_list` by value from a function does not change the value of the pointer (leading to the conclusion that the data is not copied alongside the initializer_list).

This is making it unsafe to copy an `initializer_list`, **if the copy can outlive the original object**.

- Will this behavior be maintained by further releases of the C++ standard ?
- And equally important, what would be the rationale behind this behaviour ? (it bit me really hard today, so I would naïvely say it goes against the beloved principle of "least astonishment")

Comment: No. Don't keep hold of an `initializer_list`, ever. Just say no. If you need to do that you're doing it wrong. That's not what it's for. It's for _initialization_ not as a persistent handle onto something.

Comment: The best way I've heard of putting it is: an `initializer_list` is not a container, don't treat it like one.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the C++11 standard, 18.9 [support.initlist]:

> <sup>2</sup> An object of type initializer_list provides access to an array of objects of type const E. [ Note: A pair of pointers or a pointer plus a length would be obvious representations for initializer_list. initializer_list is used to implement initializer lists as specified in 8.5.4. **Copying an initializer list does not copy the underlying elements.** — end note ]

It's like taking pointers to objects. You can also make the pointer outlive the object. If you want to do it "safely", take/store a vector of elements instead.

Copying the elements would make it expensive, and thus nobody would use it. The [documentation available](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) makes it very clear about what it does.

**EDIT:**

This is Stroustrup's proposal for `initializer_list`: [N2100](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n2100.pdf). Reading it might enlighten on its design decisions.

Comment: Since c++14, we have stronger guarantees about its lifetime, cf your link : your answer should reflect that

Comment: My reading of the C++14 version suggests it still has the same problem: making a copy of the original `initializer_list` won't extend the lifetime of the array it points to.

Comment: Thank you. But why allowing the the copy at all, if the copy is not buying any security over passing by reference/address ? (this is just digging a bit in the direction of the rationale).

Comment: Because passing a pointer+size around is very fast. You are supposed to use it in function arguments, not for storage. To store the elements you would use a `vector<T>` instead, with virtually no change in syntax.

Comment: I was not really concerned by the performance, but just by the semantic: the copy is not doing more than passing by reference from this standpoint (while having the dangers usually associated with passing by reference). I see virtually no advantage to pass the initializer_list by value over passing it by const reference.

Comment: Indeed, they could have made it non-copyable, so you could only use it by means of `const initializer_list<T>&`. Stroustrup argues that due to it being a small object, passing it by copy eases the inlining of `.begin()`, `.end()` and `constexpr` evaluation of `.size()`: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n2100.pdf

Comment: Is there a way to clone an initializer list (including copying its arguments), assuming all arguments are copyable?

Comment: @MattMcNabb As I mentioned in the comment above, use a vector if you want a copy. Creating a vector from an `initializer_list` is pretty common.

Comment: @DanielKO N2100 is a great (well, **the**) read; thanks for the link. Among other things, I really like the explanations of how the model compiler implements it and why the elements are `const` (i.e. why the object itself is treated as an _rvalue_).