# Can we use int... as an argument for template parameter pack directly?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, parameter-pack

Here is my problem:

```cpp
template <class... Ts>
struct iniClass
{
private:
    std::initializer_list<int> m_data;
    int x;

public:
    iniClass(Ts... vars)
        : m_data({vars...}), x(8)
    {
        std::cout << "created object with first constructor\n";
        prin();
    }
    void prin()
    {
        for (auto var : m_data)
        {
            std::cout << var << ", ";
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
};

int main()
{
    iniClass<std::initializer_list<int>> il1({1, 2, 3, 4}); // Work like a charm!
    iniClass<int...> il2(1, 2, 3, 4);                       // Didn't work, How to make this work?
}
```

Can we use int... (,and generally primativeTYPE...) as an argument for template parameter pack directly? 
Is there a way to make it work in that way?

Comment: Could you please provide some more background: what goal are you trying to achieve? Without that final goal, your example looks very strange: none of class data members/functions seem to depend on `Ts`, so you probably don't need a class template at all.

Comment: You shouldn't be using [`std::initializer_list<int>` as data member.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27157202/can-it-be-safe-to-keep-a-copy-of-an-stdinitializer-list-what-is-the-rationale)

Comment: Why not `std::array`?

Comment: @IgorG , I'm  just trying trying to match Ts... parameter pack using primativeTYPE... aregument :)

Comment: @JeJo is there a reason ? :)

Comment: @Scheff'sCat I hear my boss (Creference) say "std::initilialier_list" is more weighlight than std::array :)

Comment: In C++17 you don't need to specify template parameters, `iniClass il2(1,2,3,4);` will work as you expect.

Comment: @Scheff'sCat will using std::array instead help it work?

Comment: thank @康桓瑋 - this is the answer I'm looking for! :D it works!

Comment: `std::initializer_list` is meant to be used as a function argument - preferably as a constructor argument. Any other usage is strongly discouraged; it just doesn't have any benefits otherwise.

Comment: Do you really want to template **the class** and not just the constructor?

Comment: @Jarod42 yeah  perhaps I want , to try to template only the constructor too :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this feature is currently not part of the C++ standard. The closest thing we have is:

```cpp
// P1219 proposed syntax
void foo(int... args);

// C++20
void foo(std::convertible_to<int> auto&&... args);

// C++17
template <typename... Ts>
auto foo(Ts&&... args)
  -> std::enable_if_t<(std::is_convertible_v<Ts, int> && ...)>;

// C++14
template <typename... Ts>
auto foo(Ts&&... args)
  -> std::enable_if_t<CONJUNCTION<std::is_convertible<Ts, int>...>::value>;
// TODO: implement a conjunction trait like std::conjunction

// C++11
template <typename... Ts>
auto foo(Ts&&... args)
  -> typename std::enable_if<CONJUNCTION<std::is_convertible<Ts, int>...>::value>::type;
```

There is a well-received proposal which adds this feature though. See [P1219 - Homogeneous variadic function parameters](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1219r2.html). This proposal [has been rejected for C++23](https://github.com/cplusplus/papers/issues/297) by EWG (Evolution Working Group), however, it is possible that a revised version could make it into a future standard.

It doesn't really look like you need this feature though. You could just use `std::array`, which does support construction like:

```cpp
// std::make_array, (from library fundamentals TS v2) (C++26?)
// you could implement this yourself in C++11
auto arr = std::experimental::make_array<int>(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

// std::to_array, since C++20
// you could implement this yourself in C++11
auto arr = std::to_array<int>({1, 2, 3, 4, 5});

// CTAD, since C++17
std::array arr{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

// C++11, works out of the box
std::array<int, 5> arr{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

// C-style arrays
int arr[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

Your `iniClass` is basically an array anyway. Also, it's a bad idea to ever store `std::initializer_list`, because it doesn't own its contents. It's like a pointer or reference.

Comment: thanks @Jan Schultke! it was a great help!